# Convert next cron time in UTC format

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

My database has times in UTC format. When I fetch from the database it comes in a long datatype format. For eg

```
In DB - 2023-03-08 15:01:05.234081
Corresponding Long - 1678258865
```

I am having a cron expression and trying to determine the next time to be run for the particular data. For eg, the next run should be at 2023-03-09 15:00:00.234081 UTC for the above data.

```
    long prevRun = 1678258865L;
    final CronExpression cronExpression = new CronExpression("0 1 0 * * ?");
    cronExpression.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    Date date = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(prevRun)); => Outputs Tue Mar 07 23:01:05 PST 2023
    Date nextRun = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(prevRun); => Outputs Wed Mar 08 16:01:00 PST 2023
```

The fourth line always gives in the local system time zone which is why the cron gives this output.
Any advice on how I can get a new run in UTC time format for the above cron expression? I am using a cron quartz expression parser for my current use case.

Comment: Also, you want `ofEpochMilli` not `ofEpochSecond`

Comment: I just want to point out that `Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(prevRun))` produces  `Wed Nov 28 21:03:20 AEDT 55151` ... pretty sure you don't want to wait that long

Comment: Stop worrying about what things like `Date` (you should stop using this) prints by default, it's `toString` method will make use of the current local/time zone, this is what date formatters are for.  Care only that the value, if converted to UTC, is correct.

Comment: @g00se - Adding ofEpochMilli gives `Tue Jan 20 02:10:58 PST 1970`

Comment: @MadProgrammer - i ad put correct prevRun Value

Comment: 2023-03-08T07:01:05Z is what it gives me from prevRun. If you want to operate in UTC, you probably want something like `long prevRun = 1678258865000L;
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(prevRun);
ZonedDateTime prevRunZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(i, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
// Now add to prevRunZdt`

Comment: How do I determine the next cron run? The cron expression using quartz scheduler operates only on Date ? My main problem is determining next run in UTC format.

Comment: Yes you might have to convert back into to `Date` to use that API

Comment: `Date.from(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1678258865000L), ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());`.  Note `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant` will result in `2023-03-08T07:01:05Z[UTC]` and `Date.from` will result in `Wed Mar 08 18:01:05 AEDT 2023` (for me) which is correct, as AU is +11 hours ahead of UTC - stop worrying about what `Date#toString` prints

Comment: In your first example, I don’t see how that long number corresponds to that date-time mathematically; the fractional second does not match. Furthermore, your date-time lacks an indicator of time zone or offset. Is that meant to be in UTC, an offset of zero?

Comment: Why don’t you fetch your date-time from the database using `OffsetDateTime` with `ResultSet::getObject` as prescribed by JDBC 4.2+, and as described on many existing Answers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I just took a sample of a long number that was returned from the database. In the database, it's stored in UTC time format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Good night friend

```
    long prevRun = 1678298465L; // is Wed Mar 08 15:01:05 BRT
    final CronExpression cronExpression = new CronExpression("0 1 18 * * ?");
    cronExpression.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    Date date = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(prevRun)); 
    Date nextRun = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(date);
    System.out.println(date);        // Wed Mar 08 15:01:05 BRT 2023
    System.out.println(nextRun);     // Thu Mar 09 15:01:00 BRT 2023
```

Comment: May i know why did you put 18 in the cron expression?

Comment: Difference of my timezone with UTC.  In your timezone did this code work?

Comment: I found it strange that it didn't work because through cron it would be enough to define "0 * 23 * * ?", that is, run every 24 hours correct?

Comment: We've already said, more than once, that `ofEpochSecond` is the wrong way to create the `Instant`